# How do I make Ubuntu use a new Swap partition?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, swap

When I rearranged the partitions on my SSD, I stupidly deleted the swap partition and made a new one at another place instead of copying it and deleting the original. Now my Ubuntu probably doesn't find my swap partition anymore because it always takes longer than 1 minute to boot. I tried making Ubuntu use the partition in gparted but that didn't help, because it always gets turned off when I shut my computer off.

Output of `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="141bd540-84cc-4fcc-bf9b-914db6dc8ee9" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9eece7db-bee3-42b4-b254-469b16d231a0"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="Wiederherstellung" UUID="4AA28F48A28F3809" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="ca8f0733-127c-4cb4-a644-7264d92a8437"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="328F-907C" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="f04a933c-365a-4deb-819c-ab384f38f791"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="Windows" UUID="151C597062F22D20" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="a0d6cfcb-85c0-4d52-8f2c-bae46aa4d4bd"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: TYPE="swap" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="7eddf910-b128-01d6-88e0-2e3f9458eb00"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="8e7e7e06-1f83-422d-beb4-b34778e24bc2"
```

Output of `cat /etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=141bd540-84cc-4fcc-bf9b-914db6dc8ee9 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=328F-907C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=3297fa29-51d3-4be0-9701-9eafdaa1bb26 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e6188b5c-99c6-4c49-9403-5203338981b4 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Comment: Add it to `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Please add output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` commands if you need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and replace

```
UUID=3297fa29-51d3-4be0-9701-9eafdaa1bb26 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

with

```
/dev/nvme0n1p5 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: Ideally you'd find out the UUID for the new swap partition and use that, in case you add another NVMe disk or namespace later and the numbers change.

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Also PARTUUID can be used. It is good now. If anything changes, it can be updated.